# Error deploying app to tomcat

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat

I am developing an app and trying to deploy it to tomcat, but I keep getting a 500 status when trying to access the web app.

*Full error when trying to access app via tomcat*

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Root Cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Hibernate JPA Hello World Application</display-name>

<!-- Configuration for the DispatcherServlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Configuration file for the root application context -->
<!--<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>-->
```

*spring-servlet.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- It register the beans in context and scan the annotations inside beans and activate them -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.budgetbro" />

<!-- This allow for dispatching requests to Controllers -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- This helps in mapping the logical view names to directly view files under a certain pre-configured directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- This resolves messages from resource bundles for different locales -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>

<!-- To validate the posted add user form -->
<bean id="userValidator" class="com.budggetbro.validator.UserValidator" />

<!-- This produces a container-managed EntityManagerFactory;
     rather than application-managed EntityManagerFactory as in case of LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean-->
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- This makes /META-INF/persistence.xml is no longer necessary -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.budgetbro.pojo" />
    <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager.
         Exposes Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Simple implementation of the standard JDBC DataSource interface,
     configuring the plain old JDBC DriverManager via bean properties -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- This transaction manager is appropriate for applications that use a single JPA EntityManagerFactory for transactional data access.
    JTA (usually through JtaTransactionManager) is necessary for accessing multiple transactional resources within the same transaction. -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
</bean>

<!-- responsible for registering the necessary Spring components that power annotation-driven transaction management;
     such as when @Transactional methods are invoked -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

*controller class*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user-module")
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {
@Autowired
UserManager manager;

private Validator validator;

public UserController(){
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
}

@ModelAttribute("allUsers")
public List<User> populateUsers(){
    List<User> users = manager.getAllUsers();
    return users;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(Model model){
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "listUserView";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){
    Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> violations = validator.validate(user);

    for(ConstraintViolation<User> violation : violations){
        String propertyPath = violation.getPropertyPath().toString();
        String message = violation.getMessage();
        // Add JSR-303 errors to BindingResult
        // This allows Spring to display them in view via a FieldError
        result.addError(new FieldError("user", propertyPath, "Invalid "+ propertyPath + "(" + message + ")"));
    }

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "listUserView";
    }
    // Store the employee information in database
    manager.addUser(user);

    // Mark Session Complete and redirect to URL so that page refresh do not re-submit the form
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:user-module";

}
}
```

I'm completely new to tomcat and it's my first time using it so I have no idea why this is not working. I have followed tutorials online and looked up answers on this site but nothing has helped.

In the web.xml, if I comment out the `<init-param>` tags and uncomment from `<context-param>` to `</listener>` the app won't start when deploying to tomcat. But if I leave it as is the app starts and I get the error response from tomcat. This has been the furthest I have been able to progress with this and completely clueless on how to continue.

Any information regarding this would be much appreciated

**Update**

I am working on IntelliJ CE IDE. I have tomcat installed locally and I deploy my project to tomcat through maven - `mvn tomcat7:deploy`

**Project Structure**

```
[]src
  []main
    []java
    | []com
    |   []budgetbro
    |     []controller
    |       Controller.java
    []resources
      []WEB-INF
        spring-servlet.xml
        web.xml
```

Comment: "_Could not open ServletContext resource `[/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]`_". Seems like the problem.

Comment: But I have the `spring-servlet.xml` in the `WEB-INF` directory and don't understand why this error is occurring

Comment: if your are using eclipse then in server panel remove other deployed(if there are) app and redeploy it again.

Comment: Can you post the project structure? I also see spring-servlet.xml needs to have a closing tag of </beans>.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the project structure and there was always a `</beans>` tag in the `spring-servlet.xml`, it just wasn't indented and not included in the question for some reason

Comment: You project structure is **wrong** for Maven. See [the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). You seem to have webapp resources in the source resources folder. This means that when the webapp is built `spring-servlet.xml` ends up in `/WEB-INF/classes/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml`; obviously not the right place.

Comment: So if I'm reading that document correctly, I should have `spring-servlet.xml` and `web.xml` in the `src/main/webapp` directory and not in the `src/main/resources`